# creating a collection variable in MSBuild .targets

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, vsto, build-process

### Context

An annoying Excel add-in compilation bug exists and the only way I am currently able to work around it is by editing the VSTO MSBuild .targets file

- *C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\OfficeTools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.targets*

With the modification below I am able to compile the Excel add-in, **but with the side-effect that my custom ribbon is not shown any more**.

The VSTO bug and workaround are described in detail here : ["FindRibbons" task failed unexpectedly](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/651634/the-findribbons-task-failed-unexpectedly%20%22FindRibbons%22%20task%20failed%20unexpectedly)

### .targets Modification with Undesired Side-Effect of Empty RibbonTypes

```
<!--  This part is causing the compilation to fail and has to be commented out -->
<!--  <FindRibbons-->
<!--           AssemblyName="$(AbsolutePathToCustomization)"-->
<!--           TargetFramework="$(TargetFrameworkVersion)"-->
<!--        >-->
<!--  <Output TaskParameter="RibbonTypes" ItemName="RibbonTypesCollection"/>-->
<!--  </FindRibbons>-->


<!-- Now RibbonTypes is empty, causing the side-effect-->       
<!-- Used to be RibbonTypes="@(RibbonTypesCollection)"-->       
<!-- Can I manually recreate @(RibbonTypesCollection)?-->       
<GenerateOfficeDocumentManifest Condition="'$(VSTO_ProjectType)' == 'Document'"
    SolutionID="$(SolutionID)"
    RibbonTypes=""
    TargetFramework="$(TargetFrameworkVersion)"
>
```

### Filling the parameter manually?

Now I need to provide something like the following

**"ProjectNamespace.RibbonName, AssemblyName, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"**

- But I do not know exactly what form the data has to be in and I do not know MSBuild syntax either?
- How might it be possible to fill the RibbonTypes attribute manually?

Comment: The other workarounds mentioned in the link didn't work?

Comment: @KMoraz no, tried all the others, none of them worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem. It was apparently caused because I changed the "Copy Local" setting on reference "Microsoft.Office.Tools.Common.v4.0.Utilities" from True to False.

I had upgraded a project from VS2012 to VS2013 and noticed that that reference was the only one set to "Copy Local = True". So I set it to false. 'Cause it was different.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case it was a dependency on one of projects in my solution. Because of a third-party library that component was using, it had to be compiled as x86, instead of "Any CPU", as recommended for plugins.

Fortunately, in my case the fix was easy - splitting the component into "API" and "Impl" parts, compiling the API part to "Any CPU", and referencing that instead of the full component.